# How can I use Ansible to build RPM package from tar.gz tarball?

Tags: file, compression, ansible, rpm

Would like to convert a directory containing tar.gz files into RPMs
ideally being able to predefine/redefine RPM installation paths for the converted RPMs.

Here are the manual instructions:
https://access.redhat.com/sites/default/files/attachments/rpm_building_practice_10082013.pdf

Comment: And why would you use Ansible for that?

Comment: That is soo general question. While it is possible, you should know how to work with Ansible and how to create spec files. Which itself are two very general questions.

Comment: I agree and prefer to install directly from tarball, in my opinion a lot better than RPM because I can use a tar.gz readily use that in other Linux distros.. In this particular situation the vendor mostly provides tar.gz and internally our company requires RPMs to be made and stored into an internal repo.. so having an automated way to do this with ansible would be beneficial as it could be done with cron/ansible job perhaps?

Comment: @msuchy Writing spec files is not needed anymore in most cases. Unless you are a package maintainer and need fine grain control on the packaging process.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While the question is way too broad, nowadays you don't need to be able to write spec files to build rpm packages.

[fpm](https://github.com/jordansissel/fpm) automates most of the process of packaging software and take most package formats as input and output. It is really convenient when you need to package for multiple different target systems.

That said, it is convenient to modify the directory structure before packaging.